# Are there any non-windowsy ways to map a windows drive from one computer to another

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, mount

Short story, I want to transfer all files from an internal harddisk on a laptop to a temporary storage outside the laptop. Then I will wipe the disk and transfer an Ubuntu which I now run from an external USB disk on the very same laptop.

The problem is that the laptop is currently running a very enterprisey managed XP installation with disk encryption, antivirus, firewall etc so the options are few regarding normal Windows Networking (At least according to what I have discovered so far). Any attempt access other Windows machines fails. I do manage to mount a Linux smb share from a server but I cannot access the particular Windows 7 machine that I want to transfer the files to. The later I have full control over.

So can I install some other tool that allows me to map "whatever" into a drive letter so I can run [hobocopy](http://www.google.se/search?q=hobocopy) on the whole disk and hopefully never have to boot into it again. I do have local administrative rights on the laptop so I can install whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the command prompt you could try:

```
C:\> net use Z: \\server\share
```

Comment: Tried that, e:g "net use z: \\ipaddess\c$" asks for username/password then I get: "System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.."

Comment: I have also tried another username of course, same result... as well tried a real share instead of default c$

Comment: Have you tried booting up in safe mode with networking?

Answer (score 0):

```
net use * /d
```

Solved the problem with "System error 1219", trying to map the same folder again then failed with "System error 5... Access is denied" but not I could map another folder which was properly shared.

Comment: Have you tried giving "Everyone" full access to the share?